# Multi level/ multi page web scraping in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to data scraping and I have checked few resources on scrapy and beautifulsoup, but I am struggling with the following problem.

The start page URL is [here](https://www.commonfloor.com/listing-search?city=Mumbai&search_intent=sale&property_location_filter%5B%5D=region_52c256ec1614d&prop_name%5B%5D=Kandivali%20West&polygon=1&page=1&page_size=30).

I want the information such as Price, carpet is for each project and then click on the project link

Now I need to collect the content in the sections- Overview, Amenities, Specifications, etc and then go back to the previous listings page and repeat this for all the projects listed on that page. Also, hit the next button and repeat the same for all entries.

Please let me know how to implement a scraping algorithm for this use-case in python. Here is a very basic level code I tried:

```
> import pandas as pd from pandas 
> import ExcelWriter 
> import requests,re,csv from bs4 
> import BeautifulSoup
>     
> for i in range(1,5):      # Number of pages plus one 
>     
> url = "https://www.commonfloor.com/listing-search?city=Mumbai&search_intent=sale&property_location_filter%5B%5D=region_52c256ec1614d&prop_name%5B%5D=Kandivali%20West&polygon=1&page=1&page_size=30".format(i);
>     
> r = requests.get(url)    
> soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far and where do you need help, in specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a scrappy question, therefore, you should NOT include scrapy and scrapy-spider on the "tags" for the question. You are using BeautifulSoup (the old I should add), therefore the documentation you should be reading is the BeautifulSoup [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Follow the documentation, including the installation to make sure you have the updated BS4 version of BeautifulSoupSoup. I can't tell for certain that you're using the old one, but the new one you use the "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup" as the import statement. The older version you used just say "import beautifulsoup"

At the likelihood of sounding harsh, you should really know what you're using. I see that you are not clear on how to use basic python string formatting and using for loops. Would seem to me that you might benefit from giving a beginners lessons in python another try. That's not a put-down! Just saying it will be only to your benefit. ALSO...

> url =
>   "https://www.commonfloor.com/listing-search?city=Mumbai&search_intent=sale&property_location_filter%5B%5D=region_52c256ec1614d&prop_name%5B%5D=Kandivali%20West&polygon=1&page=1&page_size=30".format(i);

[image]

IN ANY CASE!

Typically, when parsing with bs4 first you make the request, initialize bs4 in a variable while declaring the type of parser... in your case, it would be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # NOT scrapy

# This is a for loop
for i in range(1,6):
    # Notice the '{}' inside the url string, when we use format, the argument
    # to it, i.e format(argument), is what does the formating
    url = "https://www.commonfloor.com/listing-search?city=Mumbai&search_intent=sale&property_location_filter%5B%5D=region_52c256ec1614d&prop_name%5B%5D=Kandivali%20West&polygon=1&page={}&page_size=30"
    #request is made
    req = requests.get(url.format(i))
    # Soup initialised to a variable and parsere declared. "lxml" in this case
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "lxml")
    items = soup.select(".snb-tile-info")
    # this will print the main div boxes with the info you want
```